# Using HttpContext.Current.Application to store values

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0

We have an ASP.NET page running on .NET Framework 4.0.

At the moment we store some values that should be available during the entire lifteime of the application in **HttpContext.Current.Application["keyToTheValue"]**.

Is this the wrong place to store values, that we need for an indefinite time,
or how can we configure the application to not recycle those values?

Oh, important to notice: We actually run the page in integrated mode, maybe this has some influence on the Application caching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is sensitive then store it in your DB for using it lifetime..it it's not that much sensitive then use persistent Cookies and set it's expiration period to max...

Comment: can you explain what you mean with **persistent** Cookies?

Comment: Persistent cookies are stored in a text file on the clients computer.Until they are expired or deleted manually..They are written like this                                                             HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("myCookie");

//Add key-values in the cookie
myCookie.Values.Add("userid", objUser.id.ToString());

//set cookie expiry date-time. Made it to last for next 12 hours.
myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(12);

//Most important, write the cookie to client.
Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie)

Comment: Depending on the exact use this could be a problem when users have cookies disabled....

Comment: thank you for the explanation, I wonder what a persistent cookie could be. But I see you mean a normal cookie :)

Comment: I'll mark yours as answer, because you list the 2 basic alternatives. one of them with a good example.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with using the Application object, but if you want to persist your data even in the event of an application close (which is bound to happen sooner or later), you might be better off storing your values in a database.

Comment: Thank you. The current scenario requires the values to be deleted upon application recycling, I just wonder how we could avoid random/unpredictable recycling of the application.

Comment: It sounds like the deletion you're not really looking to delete the values on application recycling, but based on something else that you consider to be more predictable. Perhaps store the values in a DB and then write your own code for cleaning it up on the schedule (or based on the events) that you choose. Then if you have unexpected application restarts you won't lose your data.

Comment: Is there a size limitation for `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application`?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the data, and environment, but for simple data using the application for global values is probably fine. You should look at the System.Web.Caching namespace for more advanced scenarios. Also, if you are in a web farm or cluster of some sort, you may need to roll your own global data store so you can share it across multiple servers.

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue in storing your data in Application.But it has limitation that it reset with the reset of IIS.
So use it according to your scenario.